# Get Loaded Config In Controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

How do  i get the already loaded options in the controller file in a zend framework installation without creating a new Zend_Config([ ** ]); instance.

Answer (score 6):

Once `Zend_Application` reads `application.ini`, the values are stored in bootstrap.

You may access them anywhere, without accessing the disk, or using the registry:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$bootstrap = $front->getParam('bootstrap');
if (null === $bootstrap) {
    throw new My_Exception('Unable to find bootstrap');
}

$options = $bootstrap->getOptions();
```

In the controller you may also use `$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');`

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure at all what you are asking but are you asking how to use configs set in application.ini from a controller? If so you should load that config in Zend_Registry in your bootstrap and then retrieve it in your controller.

So in bootstrap.php

```
  protected function _initConfig() {
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini("../application/configs/application.ini");
        Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    }
```

The in your Controller

```
  $myConfig = Zend_Registry::get('config');
```

Comment: oh, i thought the config was automatically loaded by the framework, so i just needed the method to get it in the controller.

Zend has like 10 different ways to do the same thing, i just wanted to make sure im not duplicating functionality. 

Thansk.s

Comment: The way I posted is the right way for sure. How about accepting my answer? Read up on how it works here http://stackoverflow.com/faq. And welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: No, it's an incorrect answer.  The bootstrap loads config automatically, you don't do it yourself...